# I am working on R using package on Drought

Tags: r, data-analysis, weatherdata

I am working using this Rstudio code

```
drought_severity <- cut(PTspei, breaks = spei_level, labels = c("D4","D3","D2","D1", "N","W1"))
```

The error message I received  is

> Error in cut.default(PTspei, breaks = spei_level, labels = c("D4", "D3",  :    'x' must be numeric.

kindly advise .

to generate drought severity. I have tried transforming the data X to numeric but couldnt get the result

Comment: Welcome to SO Omonigho Ogolo. Please run `dput(PTspei)` and add the result to your question. Also, please include the breaks as defined by "spei_level" too. This will make answering your question much easier. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.